# Typescript falsely marks variable as never

Tags: typescript, realm

I am using Realm with Typescript for NodeJS.
It has a write function that takes an arrow function which runs within a write transaction.
According to what I found on it and what‘s in the documentation it seems that write runs synchronously.

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
let myObject: MyObject | undefined = undefined;
database.write(() => {
  myObject = database.create<MyObject>('MyObject', myObjectData);
});
// using myObject here
```

The issue here is that typescript marks myObject as type never below the write operation inside the if statement. I can see that if the write would not happen and the variable being re-assigned the type would be never, but for some reason it does not detect that the variable (inside the block) is being reassigned.

Another example:

```
let myObject: MyObject | undefined;
    database.write(() => {
      myObject = database.create<MyObject>('MyObject', myObjectData);
    });
    if (myObject != undefined) {
       // myObject is of type never here according to typescript
    }
```

In this example it complains about myObject being used before its initialization.

Can anyone give me insights on how to assign a variable within a database write block? I could cast never to MyObject but I‘d much rather make typescript understand what I‘m doing than fixing its flaws.

Comment: `() = { ... }` looks suspicious

Comment: Fixing the syntax, seems to work: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeB5ARgKwKbAC7QN7QFsAKASjwF9pyAoAE03ACd1pgB7AOwh1rCzGSR0ALjzVoE6AHdGASyzoiAMw6jSAXgB80AG5tZtEqL0GA3NRrUQ6HASRpMWUQhQZs0AD7QArh3pLZDnRac15+QQh0ADoZeUVSaC0xSUJ7Nxx1aCCpODTHUnNyEnNZJWgiO1dHaABCTN9-QOCyXHFJAHp21Kr3WRg2Mqx4AAcWIJ10RmgAC0mWMGB2RlpAgHNoLDYNkfQIYDlhrDaJSodsKOISCyA

Comment: I fixed the arrow function. I wrote it out of memory on a mobile phone. It seems to work! thanks